# %20 spaces for url in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am having trouble adding spaces to my url by inserting % 20. I have tried both

```
[mystring stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

and

```
[mystring stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
```

but both of them have the same error. Whenever I look to see what they output, instead of seeing a space, I see 0X1.E2A803A48E621P-682.

I am Inserting things like "This is example text".
Has anyone ever come across this error and possible know how I could fix it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can try this way instead. NSString *newString = [mystring stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding::NSUTF8StringEncoding]; This will convert the string in to URL Encode type. Make sure you are pointing it to another instance variable.

Comment: I've already tried that but it didn't work. I have used all of these things before and they worked perfectly, but for some reason they are not working now even though I'm using the exact same code.

Comment: I just tried this and its working fine at my end. NSString *test = @"testing is fun";
    NSString *encodedString = [test stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    
    NSLog(@"%@",encodedString); Output: testing%20is%20fun

Comment: I got it to work now. I'll post the solution below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even the second example in your self-provided answer is wrong.

The method stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding does not change a string in place. It is a method that returns an escaped version of a string.

This code:

```
[new_string stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Does nothing. It creates an escaped version of the string as the result of the method call, which you ignore. You want this instead:

```
new_string = 
  [new_string stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: ... indeed the clue is in the method name. To the questioner: method names tell you exactly what they do. Read them.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, So I was using the text from a text field like this:

```
[text_field.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

or even

```
[(NSString*)text_field.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

But I fixed it by putting it first into a string and then formatting it;

```
NSString * new_string=text_field.text;
[new_string stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

And that works....I have absolutely no clue why. If anyone could post why that works and not the first two that would be amazing.

Comment: Both the first and the second versions of the code are wrong, and won't work. See my answer.